# Mechanism to save XML in SAP

Tags: xml, serialization, abap

I'm working on an SE38 upload program taking in an XML file as input.  I wish to save this XML file for audit purposes.  How can I save this file into SAP system?  Is it advisable to save this in a transparent table?  The file can be 700,000 characters long.  I also looked into Cluster tables but I was advised that this is not good and it will cause performance issues.

Does SAP system have some sort of content management mechanism where you can serialize a whole file into a storage unit?

Comment: Before I give an answer to that: do you always need to store the original XML file? Or is it sufficient to store the content fields only?

Comment: Also: What is the retention/expiration policy? Do you need to keep the file forever or will you have to delete it after some time? Do you need this to happen automatically or manually? If you're talking about auditing, do you have to provide some kind of secured storage? Do you have an external archival system using ArchiveLink available?

Comment: @AndreasHuppert Original XML

Comment: @vwegert no requirement currently for expiration.  Though I imagine we would want to delete after some time.  We want it saved upon upload of the file.  No requirement currently for secured storage

Answer (score 1):

You could simply create a transparent table with a key and a field of type `STRING`. In the project I am currently in a result of some on-the-fly calculation is persisted in such a way.
The result is stored in a DOM structure and then it is stored as XML in the before mentioned field.